# How to return the only value from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Hi I am storing the last call time of the API into DynamoDB.
And i have to read the lastcall value from DynamoDB .

DynamoDB table :

```
log{
'lastcall':'20191020235048'
}
```

now i need to pull the value (20191020235048) to query my API .
url = url+value[20191020235048].

How can i pull the value from the dynamoDB and concatenate it to url ?

Comment: Could you share the pk and the sk for your table as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand from the question, I believe you are having trouble understanding the find syntax for dynamodb.

You can use ProjectionExpression to only return a specific value from dynamoDB. 
Refer [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) for reference.

Fire a find query to the Dynamodb and use the result to concatenate it to the url.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property